# Проверка preg_math для email

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, какое выражение должно быть правильным?

Я пытаюсь использовать `/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/` , но оно не работает.

Comment: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/175375/

Comment: http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использу это:
[PhP Filter var](http://ua.php.net/filter_var)

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: За китайские не знаю, но с рускими буквами норм )

Comment: @EvgeniyMikhalichenko, `filter_var('wordpress@имя-сайта.рф', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` --> `false` или вы не об этих русских буквах говорите?

Comment: функция работает только для латиницы. адрес почты на национальном языке проверку не пройдет.

Answer (score 1):

Ни какой регуляркой вы не сможете определить реальный ли вам адрес ввели или нет.

Достаточно проверить наличие собачки в строке

```
if (strpos($email, '@') > 0) {
// отправляем проверочное письмо
}
```

и после этого отправить письмо на данный адрес для его подтверждения.

И только после подтверждения из письма вы получите 100% уверенность, что на данный момент этот адрес реален.

**UPD** [VerifyEmail](https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail) проверяет реальность email через **1.** наличие MX записей для указанного в email домена и если она(и) сушествуе(ю)т, то **2.** проверка наличие ящика через связь с этим почтовым сервером по протоколу smtp.

Comment: Не совсем верно. Пользователь мог банально очепятаться, поэтому нужно подсказать ошибку ввода. А реальность адреса проверять подтверждением отправленного письма. Если отправка вообще произойдёт :)

Comment: всегда будет точка через n символов после @

Comment: @Other, угу, как же регулярка подскажет пользователю, что он вместо буквы `k` случайно нажал `l` :P

Comment: Но от `@mail` уберечь сможет.